# Rails finding model in other model's method

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I would like to implement a server side validation for the following:
Subscriptions for a certain posting can only be created as long as the number of subscriptions doesn't exceed the number of spots for this posting.

```
    class Cposting < ActiveRecord::Base
      belongs_to :user 
      has_many :subscriptions, 
                foreign_key: "post_id", 
                dependent: :destroy
...

    def spots_left #returns the number of places left in this class
      self.spots.to_i - Subscription.where(post_id: self.id).count.to_i
    end
...
end
```

In the Subscription model I tried to call the spots_left method to determine whether there are any spots left for the Cposting a new subscription belongs to.

```
class Subscription < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :subscriber, class_name: "User"
    belongs_to :post, class_name: "Cposting"

    ...
    validate :class_not_full



def class_not_full
    Cposting.find_by(id: self.post_id).spots_left > 0 
end
end
```

Running tests on the Subscription model returned a nil error

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `spots_left' for nil:NilClass
```

It seems I can not use find_by, find or where methods to point to this Cposting.

I would like to know how to refer to the Cposting that belongs to the Subscription being validated, or an alternative way to implement this validation.

Thanks

EDIT adding tests

```
require 'test_helper'

class SubscriptionTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  def setup
    @cposting = cpostings(:one) #has one spot
    @customer = users(:customer)
    @customer2 = users(:customer2)
    @subscription = Subscription.new(post_id: @cposting.id, subscriber_id: @customer.id)
end

...

  test "subscriptions cannot exceed spots" do
    @subscription.save
    assert @cposting.subscriptions.count == @cposting.spots 
    @subscription2 = Subscription.new(post_id: @cposting.id, subscriber_id: @customer2.id)
    assert_not @subscription2.valid?
  end

end
```

Running `rake test TEST=test/models/subscription_test.rb` gives

```
  1) Failure:
SubscriptionTest#test_subscriptions_cannot_exceed_spots [/~/test/models/subscription_test.rb:37]:
Expected true to be nil or false

5 runs, 7 assertions, 1 failures, 0 errors, 0 skips
```

EDIT 2 adding create method

```
class SubscriptionsController < ApplicationController
    def create 
        @posting = Cposting.find(params[:post_id])  
        current_user.subscriptions.create(post_id: @posting.id)
        flash[:success] = "Subscribed!"
        redirect_to subscriptions_path
    end
end
```

Comment: currently your issue is `Cposting.find_by(id: self.post_id)` this returns nil. and when you try to run `spots_left` on nil class. it gives you nil:Nil class error. First please confirm `self.post_id` is present? and then also `Cposting` exists for that id

Comment: Replacing `self.post_id` with `1` also raises the nil error, while `Cposting.find_by(id: 1)` returns a valid entry in the console. Therefore, I believe the problem lies with the find_by method being called from another model than the one it's asked to search.

Comment: try this and see if it gives you error. `Cposting.find_by_id(1).try(:spots_left).to_i > 0` if this will work. then we are good that check will work fine. else we will try to debug some other way

Comment: @sso777 Can't you leverage the `belongs_to` relation and just use `post.spots_left > 0`?

Comment: @Athar I wouldn't recommend using `try` since you're just eliding the error instead of addressing the real issue: that `Cposting.find_by(id: self.post_id)` is nil when it shouldn't be.

Comment: actually i added `try` to make sure that there is no issue with find_by_id  clause, actually what you suggest i would personally go with that. but actually i'm assuming that the post is not associated yet that is why when it tries to fetch `spots_left` it wont find any and throws error @eirikir

Comment: @eirikir Your suggestion also throws up a nil error. Adding `try` runs the tests, but the validation test fails. So Athar might be right about the association not existing when the code is executed.

Comment: @sso777 Can you add the code / test that's being executed?

Comment: @sso777 it would be best if you share the controller action. from where you are creating the `Subscription` or try to log the object in `class_not_full` to see the attributes of susbscription object that post is associated or not.if not please set the post_id and i guess it will work fine

Comment: @Athar added tests and create method

Comment: okay sorry @sso777 im not good with test cases. im afraid i cant help you much with that. what i can suggest you that try to set the post_id seperately like `@subscription.post_id =  @cposting.id` before `@subscription.save`  and then test. in rails console try to create the subscriptions the way you are writing in test cases and see if it fails or not.

Answer (score 0):

Make use of the rails relations. You dont need to query everything again.

Try the following:

```
class Cposting < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user 
  has_many :subscriptions, 
            foreign_key: "post_id", 
            dependent: :destroy

  def spots_left
    self.spots - self.subscriptions.count # i assume that spots is an integer db field
  end
end
```

and

```
class Subscription < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :subscriber, class_name: "User"
  belongs_to :post, class_name: "Cposting"

  validate :class_not_full

  def class_not_full
    post.spots_left > 0 
  end
end
```

And the creation of a subscription:

```
@cposting.build_subscription(subscriber: @customer2)
```

Rails offers you a bunch of methods to choose from. You don't even need to work with the ids. Just use the relations. In general I discovered Rails to work so much smoother when you stick to the AR methods (it would even be a good idea to stick to the rails conventions when naming your tables)
 Please read [this](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html) carefully, it'll help you a lot.

Answer (score 0):

The nil error was fixed by adding a nil check and an error if the test didn't pass.

```
    validate :class_not_full

def class_not_full #checks if there are spots left for the posting
    errors.add(:post, "posting is already full") unless !post.nil? && post.spots > post.subscriptions.count 
end
```